# Win 8.1 Pro - VB.NET my own KIOSK application

Tags: vb.net, windows, kiosk

I just received my first tablet with Windows 8.1 Pro and I should create my own application that will run in KIOSK mode. I found more articles about this (see links below) but it seems that it is not easy at all.

I already know that:

- I need to use "Visual Studio 2013 for Windows", not "Visual Studio
  2013 for Windows Desktop"
- To run "Visual Studio 2013 for Windows" I need a computer with Windows 8.1
- I also need to log in to a Microsoft Account in order to run the new Visual Studio (= I need an outlook.com account)

This all is already done.

Now I created my first application (An empty application without layout) and when I run it using "Play" button in Visual Studio it works fine.

I also know how to create a new user-account under Win 8.1 (see the links) and how to assign to this user the application that the user will be allowed to use.

**The problem** is that my new exe file 1) cannot be run by it self and 2) is not in the list of applications that can be used in KIOSK mode. It needs to be installed somehow. To install an application you need to install it via the Store or using some **sideload** (see the links)

But the "sideloading" requires some certificate and the whole procedure seems to be complicated and looks more like hacking than programming.

I believe that once I have the certificate, I will be able to somehow install my exe and it will appear among applications that can be used in KIOSK mode. Am I right?

PS: My application will never be available in the Store so I cannot use its functions.

**Can someone help** me a bit? Do I have all information I need?

Once I know how to do it I will create a simple step-by-step manual for this so other people won't have to spend long hours by reading instead of working. So stay tuned if you are interested.

Links:

http://www.howtogeek.com/173562/how-to-easily-put-a-windows-pc-into-kiosk-mode-with-assigned-access/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/micham/archive/2014/05/30/sideloading-store-apps-to-windows-8-1-devices.aspx

Comment: So the first news that if you want to use for example camera in your application, you need to ask for a permission. But this won't be done automatically as one would expect. You have to go to you Solution Explorer and open the file that contains word "manifest".  In my case it was Package.appxmanifest. Tabs with settings will be shown and on tab Capabilities you have to check all devices you want to use. This isn't mentioned anywhere and you have to investigate on your own.

Comment: Info about sideloading is below, but it did not work on 100% for me (as many manuals :-) ) Everything went well, but when I wanted to launch my application as a different user, I received error "this app can't install". It may be caused by the fact that I don't know what it means "Create a new Group Policy Object (GPO)" https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx

Comment: So point 2 solved. You have to log in as non-admin user when entering commands: import-module appx and add-appxpackage “SampleApp”. Log in as the user who will use the app (in kiosk mode in my case)

Comment: FYI: You probably cannot communicate with HID Keyboard in Windows Store Application. Which means that you probably cannot catch data comming from HID USB Scanners when they simulate HID Keyboard.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn263140.aspx

Comment: I am not sure that you can do "kiosk" mode on a Windows Tablet 8.1 - Maybe on Windows 10 Tablet because that is like Windows 10 PC on tablet, if it supports docking to PC mode. You messaged me on YouTube. I did my kiosk mode with Registry hacks, replacing explorer.exe to start my app in a specific location.Cant remember now. But that worked well as long as you logged in as that account. I hope you find a solution.